# Tag synonym request: license / licence

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tag-synonyms

We currently have [licence](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licence) and [license](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license) tags, with seemingly zero overlap. These two should really be merged and established as synonyms. I recommend the US English spelling `license` for the main tag.

Comment: We don't typically use synonyms for spelling variations. Text completion and the increased rep needed to create new tags (after the private beta) should take care of it.

Comment: @RobertCartaino You should post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tag synonyms are designed to be used when there are two different words with the same meaning. We *don't* typically use synonyms for things like regional spelling variations, pluralizations, misspellings, etc.

Once we establish which tag the system prefers, the text completion and tag wiki excerpts will help users find it. We tend to standardize on the US spelling for tag usage. [Down the road a bit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/98786), it will require higher reputation to create *new* tags so this type of problem passes quickly.

Answer (score 0):

While we're on tag naming, we have [united-states](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) but not us, and both [united-kingdom](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) and [uk](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk). I would suggest that us and usa be synonyms of united-states, and uk of united-kingdom.

Comment: There is already a discussion for this: http://meta.ham.stackexchange.com/questions/6/should-we-use-short-or-long-tags-for-regional-country-tags

Comment: Yep, looks like this answer is a dupe of a dupe. Sorry, haven't read through meta yet, even though there's only a few questions.